# Black formatter ignores my pyproject.toml file

Tags: python-black

I have a simple `pyproject.toml` file for my Django projects:

```
[tool.black]
skip-string-normalization = true
skip-magic-trailing-comma = true
force-exclude = '''(manage.py|project\/|migrations\/)'''
```

This used to work until Microsoft released the Black Formatter extension for VS Code (ms-python.black-formatter).

The extension completely ignores this file. The only option I have is to add the first two lines to the extension's settings:

```
   ...
  "black-formatter.args": [
    "--skip-string-normalization",
    "--skip-magic-trailing-comma"
  ],
  ...
```

But I can't add the third one there.

So what is the solution? What I'm missing?